# Storing static void method as function

Tags: c++, function

I want to store in a vector a number of -static- functions of several classes:

```
class MyClass1
{
    static void MyFunc();
}

class MyClass2
{
    static void MyFunc();
}
```

For that, externally I am defining a vector of functions:

```
vector<function<void()>> Funcs;
```

and then storing the function using an intermediary lambda:

```
Funcs.push_back([]() { MyClass1::MyFunc(); });
Funcs.push_back([]() { MyClass2::MyFunc(); });
```

Is there a way of doing this without the use of the intermediary lambda?

Something like:

```
Funcs.pushback(&MyClass1::MyFunc);
Funcs.pushback(&MyClass2::MyFunc);
```

Comment: Did you try what you wrote under "Something like:" ? what was the result of this test?

Comment: Your question boils down to whether a class-static function can be bound to a `std::function`. Answer is: Yes. Have you tried your code? What happened? Have you tried the same with an intermediate `std::function` object, i.e. not relying on an implicit conversion?

Comment: @nivpeled Sometimes I don't understand stackoverflow. Obviously I tried what I have just posted. If I don't post anything you would ask for what I have tried. What happened is that the compiler message hasn't helped me at all, and all I needed is to change the type. I seriously do not understand why this is downvoted

Comment: @Sturm it was unclear (at least to me) that yo actually tried it, and nevertheless you did not include the compiler output/error message. Thus it is difficult for the community to conclude on what was tried and what was the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pointers to static member functions are just normal function pointers, you can define the vector as follows. You don't need `std::function` wrapper at all.

```
std::vector<void (*)()> Funcs;
```

And then:

```
Funcs.push_back(&MyClass1::MyFunc);
```